# Nginx + CakePHP cache issue

Tags: cakephp, nginx

We are deploying a CakePHP application to nginx(1.2.4).

There was an issue with the view files, it does not refresh the latest view files. 
It seems like the views are always cached, and I have to clear the browser cache in order to load the updated content.

I tried to disable in CakePHP, but the problem remains.

Anyone encountered this issue before?

**EDIT**

At the end, we figured that it is causing my the conf file under site_ available folder

Answer (score 0):

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::disableCache
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#interacting-with-browser-caching

Answer (score 0):

Check if you set debug to level to something different than 0. Debug level other than 0 sets cache for couple seconds automatically so you should be able to see latest changes for your views.